# How to ignore non alphabetic characters in c when read file

Tags: c

I am reading a file using `fscanf`. I want to ignore non alphabetic characters like commas, \ , :, and dots.

This is my code:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(fl,"r");
char c[50];

while(fscanf(fp, "%s" ,c)!= EOF){
    linkLst(c);

}

fclose(fp);
```

how do I read file word by word ignoring non alphabetic characters?

{
part of the file as follows

WITH ANSWERS:

1) What written language is the most complicated in the world? (Hint: It
uses four character sets.) (Is this question too easy?)  >> Japanese

2) What language has a vocabulary primarily of Arabic origin (about 70%,
I'm told), but uses the Roman alphabet? (I'd like to know where you found
the answer!)  >> Maltese

3) What non-Romance language uses a tilde (~) over the letter N? >> Estonian
}

Comment: Call `isalpha` on the characters you read?

Comment: Please provide the function declaration for `linkLst`.

Comment: Could you give us an example of a line from the input file and the corresponding string you want to pass to `linkLst`? Don't answer in a comment but edit your question.

Comment: I added a part of the file

Comment: Also can you specify what is the expected behavior? What should go into the linkLst?

Comment: "I want to ignore non alphabetic characters like commas, \ , :," --> Should code _ignore_ them or use them as _word_ separators?  `abc:def` --> 1 word  `abcdef` or 2 words `abc`, `def`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to stick to reading the content "word by word" rather than worrying about the linked list.

`scanf` family of functions gives you the ability to do trivial parsing, there's no need to do it character by character as enough functionality is available in scanf.  If you want to parse the strings char by char then  simply use `fgets` and perform the parsing you need.

I'll stick with scanf as that's what you're using:

Starting with a simple file (*foo.txt*) containing:

> hello there, how are you?

and trying to scanf it:

### bad example 1:

```
/* NOTE: this code does NOT do what you want */
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char foo[128];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("foo.txt", "r");
    do {
        sscanf(input, "%[A-Za-z0-9]", foo);
        fprintf(stderr, "foo: %s\n", foo);
    } while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

You get an infinite loop printing `hello` because scanf is stuck and cannot mung the space after "hello".

So let's add a munger:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char foo[128];
    char mung[128];
    char rv = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("foo.txt", "r");
    do {
        rv = fscanf(fp, "%[A-Za-z0-9]%[^A-Za-z0-9]", foo, mung);
        if(rv == EOF)
            break;
        fprintf(stderr, "foo: %s\n", foo);
    }while(1);
}
```

So munger munges everything that's not in the foo character set that we're looking for (putting a `^` inside the [] as the first character makes scanf negate the content).

This will print out:

```
 foo: hello
 foo: there
 foo: how
 foo: are
 foo: you
```

Now if we are being clever we can skip the assignment of the mung variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char foo[128];
    char rv = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("foo.txt", "r");
    do {
        rv = fscanf(fp, "%[A-Za-z0-9]%*[^A-Za-z0-9]", foo);
        if(rv == EOF)
            break;
        fprintf(stderr, "foo: %s\n", foo);
    }while(1);
}
```

Obviously in my examples I've assumed that foo is less than 128 bytes. However we don't know that, well scanf (after 2001 POSIX standard) allows you go to dynamically allocate memory for character strings which you have to `free` later on, so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *foo;
    char rv = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("foo.txt", "r");
    do {
        /* notice the & before foo, because fscanf will modify the pointer
         * variable itself and assign it a new pointer after allocating 
         * the space for the string
         */
        rv = fscanf(fp, "%m[A-Za-z0-9]%*[^A-Za-z0-9]", &foo);

        if(rv == EOF)
            break;

        fprintf(stderr, "foo: %s\n", foo);
        /* store the foo pointer somewhere for use and free it later,
         * if you are sticking it in a linked list, then you should 
         * free it whenever you free the corrosponding node.
         *
         * I am just going to free it here after printing it out
         */
        free(foo); 
    }while(1);
}
```

## Update

As BLUEPIXY points out this would not eat up any characters that begin with non-matching chars. So something like,

> )) oops helo

will get stuck in a `(null)` loop

Which means we need to make munging a separate operation so that it eats things up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *foo;
    char rv = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("foo.txt", "r");
    do {
        /* notice the & before foo, because fscanf will modify the pointer
         * variable itself and assign it a new pointer after allocating 
         * the space for the string
         */
        rv = fscanf(fp, "%m[A-Za-z0-9]", &foo);

        if(rv == EOF)
            break;

        /* foo would be null if scanf didn't read anything */
        if (foo) {
             fprintf(stderr, "foo: %s\n", foo);
        /* store the foo pointer somewhere for use and free it later,
         * if you are sticking it in a linked list, then you should 
         * free it whenever you free the corrosponding node.
         *
         * I am just going to free it here after printing it out
         */
             free(foo); 
        }


        rv = fscanf(fp, %*[^A-Za-z0-9]");

        if (rv == EOF) 
             break;

    }while(1);
}
```

(see scanf(3)) page for details

Comment: For example, input does not work as expected if it begins with parentheses(or newline or etc).

Comment: yes but it can easily be adapted to take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a copy of the string you read filtering out the non alphanumeric characters.

After the `scanf` do this

```
char str[50];
int index = 0;
int index2 = 0;
while(c[index] != '\0') {
    if (isalpha((unsigned char)c[index]))
        str[index2++] = c[index];
    else{
        str[index2] = '\0'; 
        if (index2 != 0)
            linkLst(str);
        index2 = 0; 
    }    
    index++;    
}
str[index2] = '\0';
if (index2 != 0)
    linkLst(str);
```

Comment: Wow, instant DV! May I ask the reason?

Comment: if input like `name:value`,  `namevalue` is added to the list.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I think that is what OP wants. *I want to ignore none alphabetic characters like commas, \ , :, and dots*

Comment: So OP wants `ABC DEF GHI` to `ABCDEFGHI`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY he is using `"%s"` to scan strings. SO not spaces. My understanding is he wants to read multiple strings separated by space and call `linkLst` after filtering special characters from the strings.

Comment: So why do you need to join in cases other than white-spaces?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am not joining any strings. I am just filtering the non alpha numberic characters. For the input `abcd:123 efgh/456 ijkl,789` I am adding `abcd123`, `efgh456` and `ijkl789` to the linked list.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. However, your code yields the results shown above.(`name:value` to  `namevalue`)

Comment: Isn't that is what is expected? He also wants to filter `:`

Comment: I think it should be treated as a separate word. E.g if input as `isalpha(c[index]))` to `isalpha` , `c` and `index`, not `isalphacindex`

Comment: [I am adding abcd123](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893852/how-to-ignore-non-alphabetic-characters-in-c-when-read-file#comment74822912_43894055) certainly does not meet [read file word by word ignoring non alphabetic characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43893852/2410359)

Comment: Note: `if (isalpha(c[index]))` is UB when `c[index] < 0` and not `EOF`.

Comment: @chux would `isalpha((unsigned char) c[index])` be fine?

Comment: @chux, regarding the other issue, OP is not clearing anything after repeatedly asking. Anyway, I will change the code to add different words on seeing a non alpha numeric character.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is this solution okay?

Comment: At least I like it better than before. (^з^)-☆Chu!!

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya `isalpha((unsigned char) c[index])` is the typical fix.   This and other issues are minor (no length limit, braces style).  Good improvement.

Comment: So actually OP's char array `c` had a length limit of 50. So I used the same limit. And I didn't get your point about braces style.

Answer (score -1):

Filter out each character with `isalpha` function.

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%s", c) != EOF) {
    char* ptr = c;
    while (*ptr) {
        if (isalpha(*ptr)) {
            linkLst(*ptr);
        }
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

And correct function `linkLst` to accept character by character instead of character pointer.

If `linkLst` is mandatory for `char *` as parameter, you can do it like this:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%s", c) != EOF) {
    char* ptr = c;
    char tmp[2] = {0, 0};
    while (*ptr) {
        if (isalpha(*ptr)) {
            tmp[0] = *ptr; 
            linkLst(tmp);
        }
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since OP has called `linkList` on `c` it would appear that it takes `char*`. You are passing a char.

Comment: Did you saw my statement on last line or not?

Comment: But what if `linkLst` needs `char*` ?

Comment: OP is passing the entire string he reads to `linkLst`. All he wants to do is filter our non alpha numeric characters. I don't understand why you insist on passing it character by character?

Comment: You can pass string multiple times, can't you? I've also updated the code, don't be silly, please.

Comment: @But he needs the entire string. How difficult is that to understand?

Comment: If while loop is in use I assume linkLst can be called multiple times. So if it is even more times, I don't see a problem. Again, why are you so silly? @AjayBrahmakshatriya

Comment: Are you implying that calling `linkLst("abc")` and `linkLst("a"); linkLst("b"); linkLst("c");` are the same? Well what if they are not?

Comment: His code creates __1__ node in the linked list with the entire string. Your code creates __3__ nodes with "a" "b" and "c". How do you not understand that they are not the same?

Comment: But noone said that can't be the same!

Comment: I don't see linkLst and until I don't see it we can only argue. I'm done just now!

Comment: Exactly! No one said they are same or not. So you should stick to the behavior shown in the question and not invent possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

Include header `#include <ctype.h>` which includes a function `isalpha(char c)` which returns `true` if `c` is a alphabetic character.

```
if ( isalpha(c))
{
     // do what you wanna do
}
else 
{
     // ignore
}
```

Otherwise, you can use the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Use characters as if they were `int` and compare them. For example, to check if a `char` is a alphabetic and capital, you'd do :

```
if ( c < 66 && c > 90)
{
    // do what you wanna do
}
else 
{
    // ignore
}
```

If `c` is a tab, then loop into it like that :

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(c); i++) // Then use c[i] to access to char inside it
{
    if (c[i] < 66 && c[i] > 90) // or if (isalpha(c[i])
    {
        // do what you wanna do
    }
    else 
    {
       // ignore
    }
}
```

You could also write :

```
if (c[i] < 'A' && c[i] > 'Z')
```

Because thanks to ASCII table, `'A' == 66` and `'Z' == 90`

Comment: @Badda how can you compare `c` which is a `char[]` with the integers 66 and 90?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya As I said below, use a loop and access to char which are inside `char[]`with `char[i]`. I can add an example if you want

Comment: @Badda Please: what are those magic numbers `66` and `90`? __I__ know what they are, but you can write these differently, I'm sure you know it.

Comment: @Badda then in your loop, shouldn't you be using `c[i]` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well you can write `'A'` and `'Z'` directly, but writing this would not explain how ASCII table works.

Comment: @Badda `if (c < 66 && c > 90)` this doesn't make sense!! replace c with c[i].

Comment: @Badda `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(c); i++) // Then use c[i] to access to char inside it
{
    if (c < 66 && c > 90) // or if (isalpha(c[i])
    {
        // do what you wanna do
    }
    else 
    {
       // ignore
    }
}` C is a char here? Will you read your own answer __once__?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Corrected.

Comment: @Badda now it makes sense. PS: the Downvote is not from me.